# Java 8 stream throws EntityNotFoundException on Optional

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I try to use a Java 8 stream to map a `List<Entity>` of entities.

```
entities.stream()
            .map(entity -> 
                 entityService.getById(entity.getId())
                .orElseGet(Entity::new))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem is that `getById()` throws `JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException` / `EntityNotFoundException`.

I thought that if the `getById()` returns a Optional of Entity, `orElseGet()` would get the `Entity` or create a new one.

Service

```
Optional<Entity> getById(long id);
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Override
public Optional<Entity> getById(final long id) {
    return entityRepository.findById(id);
}
```

EntityRepository extends JpaRepository

```
Optional<Entity> findById(long id);
```

Update:

`findById(id)` is implemented automatically by JpaRepository.

Comment: And what does `processingEntity` do?

Comment: jpa session `get` method will throw that `EntityNotFoundException` if no entity was found.

Comment: Well, how does `EntityRepository` implement `getById`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think the OP just using `em.get(id)`, :)

Comment: @holi-java Well, it doesn't appear anywhere in the question, so we need to know for sure.

Comment: @RealSkeptic JpaRepository< Entity, Long > is creating automatically the query for my findById method and returns an Optional of Entity.

Comment: @holi-java Should I override the findById method to catch the EntityNotFoundException ?

Comment: @user3450862 you can replace method  `getById` with `findById` which return `null` if entity not exists. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)

Comment: Your stream handling is fine, assuming that `findById()` returns `Optional.empty()` when the SQL query comes back empty. So your real question is "why does my Spring JPA class throw an exception instead of returning `Optional.empty()`". Write a unit test for your repository class, and work at it until it stops throwing exceptions. Glancing at Spring docs, it looks as if it should be possible. You shouldn't need to catch the exception.

Comment: does your entity has @Id annotation ?

Comment: @GeorgeMoralis Yes, for the 'id'. But in this case, I'm not searching for the entity by that id, but by another fied (I have anotherId and I search for it with findByAnotherId). I didn't expect this could be a problem so I simplified here for the question saying just findById.

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception.